# Segmentation fault while trying to sort strings in C

Tags: c, sorting, segmentation-fault

I am simply trying to read from a text file, parse some information into an "array of strings" and then alphabetize the array using qsort. However, I keep getting a segmentation fault during the sorting part. I am new to C, can anybody take a look at my code and tell me what the problem is?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int compare (const void * a, const void * b ) {
  return strcmp(*(char **)a, *(char **)b);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r"); // argv[1] = "input.txt"
    char allStrings[255][255];
    int stringArrCounter = 0;

    char buff[255]; /* String to put the scanned shit in*/
    char blank[255];
    strcpy(blank, " ");

    int counter = 0;
    while (!feof(fp)){
        char stringer[255];
        char stringer2[255];
        fgets(buff, 255, fp);
        if (strcmp(buff, blank) > 0){
            if (counter % 5 == 0){
                strncpy(stringer, buff, strlen(buff)-1);
            }
            else if (counter % 5 == 1){
                strncat(stringer, buff, strlen(buff)-1);
            }
            else if (counter % 5 == 3){
                strncpy(stringer2, buff, strlen(buff)-10);
                strncat(stringer2, stringer, strlen(stringer));
            }
            else if (counter % 5 == 4){
                strcpy(allStrings[stringArrCounter], stringer2);
                printf("%s\n", stringer2);
                memset(stringer,0,sizeof(stringer));
                memset(stringer2,0,sizeof(stringer2));
                stringArrCounter++;
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }
    qsort(allStrings, 255, sizeof(char *), compare);
}
```

Comment: You code expibits undefined behaviour. Your compiler should warn and you should pay heed to them. Get the types correct, instead of just using `void *` and casting.

Comment: Can you show us where you're getting the seg fault? Line #?

Comment: I'm sorry, this is literally the first thing I've done in C. Olaf, are you talking about the comparator? StephenG, how do I get the line num?

Comment: Rather than `while (!feof(fp)){`, use `while (fgets(buff, sizeof buff, fp) != NULL){`  Also remove \n with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/27729970#27729970

Comment: And... the size of each element in `allStrings` is *not* `sizeof(char*)`. Taking away everything else that is wrong, that along has implosion written all over it.

Comment: With `strncpy(stringer, buff, strlen(buff)-1);`, `stringer` is not null character terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short example of how to use `qsort` with a 2-D array.  Note that a 2-D array is different to an array of pointers. It is a contiguous bloc of characters and the compiler will compute offsets in response to the dimensions you give.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int comp10(void const *p1, void const *p2)
{
    typedef char const A[10];

    return strcmp( *(A *)p1, *(A *)p2 );
}

int main()
{
    char arr[3][10] = { "pangolin", "fish", "anteater" };

    qsort(arr, sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0], sizeof arr[0], comp10);

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]; ++i)
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
}
```

---

Setting up the comparison function and the `qsort` call correctly is your main issue.

However your code to read the strings from file contains a number of mistakes. Please consult the manual pages for `strncpy` and `strncat` and `fgets` to see what the arguments mean and what output they generate. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) for how to use `feof` (hint: you should not use it at all).

I would recommend you divide your program into two parts:

1. The sorting logic, which you will test by using a hardcoded list of strings as in my example
2. The file reading logic, which you will test by outputting the strings you have read.

Once both tests succeed , then you can feed the output of (2) into the input of (1).